# if connect a diode to an AC signal can it be kept forward bias with increasing voltage at n-side?

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, power-electronics, current-source, bias

if I connect a diode to an AC signal can it be kept forward bias with increasing voltage at n-side?

Is Vx going to be Vi even after Vi>4.5 because it seems to be reverse biased. here's my circuit and assumed output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi will become blocked by the diode D1 above 4.5V, while D2 conducts and thus Vx cannot exceed ~0.7 + 4.5 so this acts as a peak limiter at Vx.

Diode drop depends on current rating relative to 100mA source and Vi is assumed ideal ESR=0.

[image]
Note D1 conducts only below blocking voltage and D2 conducts above blocking voltage of battery.

If the signal on left was another variable battery and current source is a generator, we call this **a "battery isolator" circuit** so that the lowest battery gets charged yet neither discharges the other.

Comment: but LTSpice gave result as shown in right side( red: Ib ) How?

Comment: pilot error? only the D2 current looks like that.  Vx will be a clipped sinewave at +5.25V

Comment: D2 goes to -100mA only when **V1's** positive cycle How?  How **D2 Current** is controlled by V1?

Comment: lowest side sinks the current. Thy would share if equal

Comment: thank you very much now i get it.my lecturer taught us D1  is kept FB lol

Comment: If you had not indicated sine was 10Vp and was the same 4.5Vp then D1 is always FB and D1 would the be sharing 100mA equally only at the peak.  YOu must learn to catch your lecturer's slips and watch out for your own, when you graduate. It will happen. Often we learn best from mistakes.